# Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a tagging function so users can tag via `@` sign or # sign but the problem is that via `@` sign it is working fine but via `#` sign it is not getting any thing I am unable to figure out the error as of when I place `console.log below the if(go.length>0) {` condition it is not giving me anything but when I place just above the first if condition `if(go.length>0) {` it is giving me in return value I do not know what the problem is in console I also found an error  Cannot read property 'length' of null against this go.length Can any one help me out here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

var co_start=/#/ig;
var co_word=/#(\w+)/ig;

$("#contentbox").on("keyup",function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    var go      = content.match(start);
    var name    = content.match(word);
 
 var content1 = $(this).text();
 var go_com  = content1.match(co_start);
    var co_name = content1.match(co_word);
    var len = $.trim($('#contentbox').text()).length;

    if (len >= 200) {
  content.text = content.text.substring(0, 200);
    } else {
  $('#charNum').text(200 - len);
    }

    if(go.length>0) {
        $("#display").slideUp('show');
        if(name.length>0) {
            $.ajax({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_user",
                data     : {searchword: name, word: word, command: 'Search User'},
                cache    : false,
                success  : function(html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });

        }
    } else {
  alert('Helo World');
  if(go_com.length>0) {
   $("#display").slideUp('show');
   if(co_name.length>0) {
    $.ajax({
     type     : "POST",
     url      : "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_tag_company",
     data     : {searchword: co_name, co_word: co_word, command: 'Search Company'},
     cache    : false,
     success  : function(html) {
      $("#display").html(html).show();
     }
    });

   }
  }
 }
 
    return false();
});
});
```

```css
#contentbox {
  with: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true" name="post_dt">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` does not have a length.  The easiest way is to check if this object is not null and then see if the value has a length `if ( not_null && not_null.length )`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var start = /@/ig;
  var word = /@(\w+)/ig;

  var co_start = /#/ig;
  var co_word = /#(\w+)/ig;

  var $contentbox = $('#contentbox'),
    $charNum = $('#charNum'),
    $display = $('#display');

  $contentbox.on('keyup', function() {
    var $box = $(this),
      content = $box.text(),
      go = content.match(start),
      name = content.match(word);

    var go_com = content.match(co_start),
      co_name = content.match(co_word),
      len = $.trim($contentbox.text()).length;

    if (len >= 200) {
      content.text = content.text.substring(0, 200);
    } else {
      $charNum.text(200 - len);
    }

    if (go && go.length) {
      $display.slideUp('show');
      if (name && name.length) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_user",
          data: {
            searchword: name,
            word: word,
            command: 'Search User'
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $display.html(html).show();
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      alert('Helo World');
      if (go_com && go_com.length) {
        $display.slideUp('show');
        if (co_name && co_name.length ) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_tag_company",
            data: {
              searchword: co_name,
              co_word: co_word,
              command: 'Search Company'
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
              $display.html(html).show();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
#contentbox {
  with: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true" name="post_dt">
  <div id="data"></div>
</div>
<div id="charNum">200</div>

<div id="display">Display</div>
```

Comment: Thank you your code really works can you please explain me what actually you did I noticed you have changed some of my ajax code as well and unable to recognize it have you used OOP?

Comment: @MarkAlan no, I just hit the "Tidy" button.  The big difference is going from `if (go.length>1)` to `if (go && go.length)`, which says *if `go` is not null, then if `go` has a length, do the following code*.  Other than that I just put things in variables, especially things that you were doing more than once (e.g., `$(this)`)

Comment: perfect you really helped me alot and I lie the style of coding I will make it practice of this

Comment: @MarkAlan there's a lot more you can look at to make it DRYer (don't repeat yourself) and more efficient.  I didn't apply that here, but if you continue to read up on it and look at good examples, it'll come in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit to check if the your values is not equal to `null` and i really recommend not to use `keyup` since it will send a request each time the **user** hit the `keyboard` but it's up to you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var start=/@/ig;
var word=/@(\w+)/ig;

var co_start=/#/ig;
var co_word=/#(\w+)/ig;

$("#contentbox").on("blur",function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    // var start=/@/ig;
    var go      = content.match(start);
    var name    = content.match(word);
    
    var content1 = $(this).text();
    var go_com  = content1.match(co_start);
    var co_name = content1.match(co_word);
    var len = $.trim($('#contentbox').text()).length;

    if (len >= 200) {
        content.text = content.text.substring(0, 200);
    } else {
        $('#charNum').text(200 - len);
    }

console.log(content.match(start))

    if(go != null && go.length > 0) {
        $("#display").slideUp('show');
        if(name !=null && name.length>0) {
            $.ajax({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_user",
                data     : {searchword: name, word: word, command: 'Search User'},
                cache    : false,
                success  : function(html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });

        }
    } else {
        alert('Helo World');
        if(go_com != null && go_com.length>0) {
            $("#display").slideUp('show');
            if(co_name.length>0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type     : "POST",
                    url      : "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_tag_company",
                    data     : {searchword: co_name, co_word: co_word, command: 'Search Company'},
                    cache    : false,
                    success  : function(html) {
                        $("#display").html(html).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
});
});
```

```css
#contentbox {
  with: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true" name="post_dt">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the main problem. Your regex is wrong, and js too.

In order to capture the #, you need to add a \ before it

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/cvdjt2xx/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var start=/@/gim;
    var word=/@(\w+)/gim;
    
    var co_start=/\#/gim;
    var co_word=/\#(\w+)/gim;
    
    $("#contentbox").on("keyup",function() {
        var content = $(this).text();
        var go      = content.match(start);
        var name    = content.match(word);
     
      var go_com  = content.match(co_start);
        var co_name = content.match(co_word);
        var len = $.trim($('#contentbox').text()).length;
    
        if (len >= 200) {
        $('#charNum').text('0');
        content.text = content.text.substring(0, 200);
        } else {
        $('#charNum').text(200 - len);
        }
        
        if (go && go.length > 0) {
      alert('@');
            $("#display").slideUp('show');
            if(name.length>0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type     : "POST",
                    url      : "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_user",
                    data:{searchword:name,word: word, command: 'Search User'},
                    cache    : false,
                    success  : function(html) {
                        $("#display").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
    
            }
        } 
//else {
    //  alert('Helo World');
      if(go_com && go_com.length>0) {
      alert('#');
       $("#display").slideUp('show');
       if(co_name.length>0) {
        $.ajax({
         type     : "POST",
       url: "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/search_tag_company",
         data     : {searchword: co_name, co_word: co_word, command: 'Search Company'},
         cache    : false,
         success  : function(html) {
          $("#display").html(html).show();
         }
        });
    
       }
      }
        //alert('action');
     //}
     
        return false();
    });
    });
```

```css
#contentbox {
  with: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true" name="post_dt">
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="charNum">200</div>

<div id="display">Display</div>
```